# Removing doubling lines

Tags: sql, sql-server, union, distinct

I have written a union query but I need to eliminate the lines that are duplicated (line 2 and 3 in the column 'kods') and leave only distinct values of column 'kods'. How can that be done?

[image]

Comment: Are you using UNION or UNION ALL? UNION will eliminate duplicates by default. If a line isn't getting removed in a UNION, then one of the columns isn't DISTINCT.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors/data when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Union two selects removing duplicates base on some columns (not the full row)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24384486/union-two-selects-removing-duplicates-base-on-some-columns-not-the-full-row)

Comment: Also, using `DISTINCT` with a `UNION` query is redundant. The `UNION` is already enforcing the dataset to be only contains distinct rows.

Comment: It's not giving you duplicates, because "Ilze Ozola" has two distinct records. They are each distinct because they each have a different id of 77 and 2. So if you removed the id from your `select` statement, it will only show you that name once.

Comment: Edit your question and describe the logic you want to implement.  How do you choose which row to keep?

Comment: @GordonLinoff i only need rows with distict values of ''kods''

Comment: Which value for `id` do you want?

Answer (score 0):

You need to decide which of the id values to discard using either `min` or `max` and group by the remaining columns. you don't need `distinct` and can `union all` since `group by` will perform the dedupe.

```
select kods, min(id) id, vards, uzvards from (
  select kods, id, vards, uzvards
  from dataset
  union all
  select kods, id, vards, uzvards
  from dataset_2
)x
group by kods, vards, uzvards
```